# How to search a file using a regex for a variable in Python

Tags: python, regex, variables

I'm trying to search a file, PDB, for a variable, atom, that is determined by the user input. The file is also a variable determined by user input. I've looked at similar problems, but when I try to implement my code I get the error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects". 
This is my code:

```
match = re.search((r'\s') + atom + (r'\s'), PDB.read())
```

could someone tell how to fix the error/my problem?

Comment: from the looks of it your `atom` is an int so you can't concatenate it with string like objects.

Comment: `str(atom) ` will make any int a string, what do you want to do with the match?

Comment: Regex patterns are usually strings and hence I guess `str(atom)` will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
match = re.search((r'\s') + repr(atom) + (r'\s'), PDB.read())
```